# How to get running time using the clock () function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
  time_t startTime, endTime;
  while(1)
  {
    startTime = clock();
    /*
       Some processing
    */
    endTime = clock();
    gap = (int)((endTime - startTime) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
    printf("StartTime: %d, EndTime: %d\n", (int)startTime, (int)endTime);
    printf("RunningTime: %d sec", gap);
  }
}
```

Output:
StartTime: 1962, EndTime: 19247
RunningTime: 0 sec

I found out that this happens because CLOCKS_PER_SEC is 1,000,000 on Ubuntu.
Can I calculate CLOCKS_PER_SEC as 1,000 as in Windows?

Comment: You cannot "calculate" CLOCKS_PER_SEC. It's a given. You should determine what you want to output if your execution time is less than.one second.

Comment: By the way the semantics of `clock` is non-standard on Windows, so if you want portable results you should not be using this function.

Comment: Did you read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)? For Linux you should!

Comment: `clock()` returns `clock_t` not `time_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>(I am focusing on Linux)</sup>

Read first [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). Then read [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html), [getrusage(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html), [times(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/times.2.html), [clock(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html) (the notes are important).

There are several different notions of time: real, elapsed, process CPU, thread CPU. You need to choose the right one. Notice that some functions return time in seconds and microseconds or nanoseconds (using some `struct`). You might want to convert them to a `double` (and sometimes lose precision). Notice that real wall clock time might change (e.g. [adjtimex(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/adjtimex.2.html)...) in some unexpected (non-monotonic) way.

On some cheap systems (notably 32 bits embedded Linux systems), be aware of the [Y2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)

> Can I calculate CLOCKS_PER_SEC as 1,000 as in Windows?

`CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is semantically a constant that you cannot change (even on Windows). It is provided by the system (and on POSIX is *required* to be 1000000, so on Linux `clock()` gives process CPU µs). See also [sysconf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html) for `_SC_CLK_TCK` (relevant for [times(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/times.2.html)).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `endTime`, `startTime` and `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` are all *integers*. You need to cast at least one of the values to a floating point type. *And* use a floating point type for destination.

E.g.

```
double gap = (double) (endTime - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("RunningTime: %f sec", gap);
```